# drawing rectangles on an image in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to write a simple java script program to mark rectangles on an image. You click a button to add a rectangle then you click on the upper left and lower right corner and the program should mark the rectangle in red. I'm using straight javascript with jquery.

Everything almost works, except when either the upper left or lower right corner of a rectangle is inside another rectangle in that case, while the click event gets processed, the x and y are incorrect.

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for hours and google didn't help. I specifically tried:

- changing the e.pageX for e.screenX and e.screenY
- using the absolute position (the top and left) instead of the offset

It is clear I'm missing something that is not allowing me to get this just right, but I don't know exactly what.

I've created a [jsfiddle with an example that shows the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/65FDe/4/). Yet in case you don't want to click on it, this is my JS code:

```
var rects = [{x1: 708, y1: 246, x2: 738, y2: 277},
             {x1: 442, y1: 239, x2: 474, y2: 271},
             {x1: 676, y1: 242, x2: 703, y2: 270}];

var $container = $("#container");
var click_count = 0;
var added_rects = 0;
var waiting_for_clicks = false;
var new_rects = [];
var current_rect = {};

var add_rect = function(color, rect) {
    $('<div class="child"/>')
    .appendTo($container)
    .css("left", rect.x1 + "px")
    .css("top", rect.y1 + "px")
    .css("width", (rect.x2-rect.x1)+"px")
    .css("height", (rect.y2-rect.y1)+"px")
    .css("border", "1px solid " + color);
};

var remove_last_rect = function() {
    if (new_rects.length > 0) {
        $container.children('div:last-child').remove();
        new_rects.pop();
    }
}
_.map(rects, _.partial(add_rect, 'red'));

var listen_for_rect = function() {
    click_count = 0;
    waiting_for_clicks = true;
    current_rect = {x1: -1, y1: -1, x2: -1, y2: -1};
    $('#add-rect').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#remove-rect').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
};

var stop_listening_for_rects = function() {
    waiting_for_clicks = false;
    $("#add-rect").removeAttr('disabled');
    $('#remove-rect').removeAttr('disabled');
    add_rect('red', current_rect);
    new_rects.push(current_rect);
}

$('#add-rect').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    listen_for_rect();
});

$('#remove-rect').click(function(e) {
    remove_last_rect();
    if (new_rects.length == 0) $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});

var click_event = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (waiting_for_clicks) {
        click_count++;
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var x = e.pageX-offset.left;
        var y = e.pageY-offset.top;
        console.log(x);
        console.log(y);
        if (click_count == 1) {
            current_rect.x1 = x;
            current_rect.y1 = y;
        } else if (click_count == 2) {
            current_rect.x2 = x;
            current_rect.y2 = y;
            stop_listening_for_rects();
        }
    }
};

$container.on('click', '.child', click_event);

$('img').click(click_event);
// console.log($('.child'));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you click inside of a rect, then the x and y co-ordinates are **relative** to the top left corner of the rect, rather than the top left corner of the image.

The reason is, $(this).offset() returns the offset of the element you're clicking in, not the offset of the image, so when you click inside of a rect it returns the offset of the rect.

Try this in `click_event = function(e) {`:

```
var offset = $("img").offset();
```

Comment: Thanks! That is really flexible, I totally missed it. Here's the fixed jsfiddle in case anyone lands on this page: http://jsfiddle.net/65FDe/6/